# Leading/Lagging terminology for sinusoidal waves

Tags: waves

Is there a method to identify which wave is leading and which wave is lagging from their equations?

For example, if the two waves are $A\sin(\omega t+\pi/6)$ and $A\sin(\omega t+2\pi)=A\sin(\omega t)$ (by trigonometric relations), is the second wave leading in phase or lagging in phase compared to the first? Or we can say both is true?

What is the convention to be followed when we say "wave A leads wave B..." ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start from $y_1= A\sin(\omega t)$ and compare it with $y_2= A\sin(\omega t+ \phi)$ you find that time  $t=0$ motion $1$ has a displacement of $y_1=0$ and motion $2$ has a displacement of $y_1=\sin \phi$.

[image]

You will see that whatever motion $2$ does motion $1$ does a little later in time so motion $2$ leads motion $1$ by phase angle $\phi$.

So the more positive $\phi$ represents the motion which is leading.

However it is also true the motion $1$ lags motion $2$ by phase angle $\phi$.

The way you have written the two motions your second motion leads your first motion by $2\pi-\frac \pi 6$.

However if your two motions had been given as $A\sin(\omega t + \frac \pi 6)$ and $A\sin(\omega t)$ and no other information was given you would say that the first motion leads second motion by phase angle $\frac \pi 6$.

Comment: Right, but I'd add that the case shown in the diagram, where motion 2 leads motion 1, corresponds to the condition $\phi > 0$. For $\phi < 0$, it's the other way round.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Thank you. I have made a slight change to my answer to make it clearer as to how to deal with negative values of $\phi$.